# loadkeys and SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, keyboard-layout

I would like my remote SSH server to recognize <kbd>F11</kbd> as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. For example when I press "<kbd>F11</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>" I want Linux to recognize it as a "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>"

1. Loadkeys doesn't work, since I'm connecting through the SSH, and therefore I don't have scancodes to transform them.
2. And I can't modify SSH client(since I'm connecting from the different machines), only the server.
3. I have root access on the remote machine.
4. Remote machine is Ubuntu without X Server. I have console access too.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to remap keymaps on the /remote/ machine, but the terminal your SSH /client/ runs on.  Thus using `loadkeys` on your client machine should do the trick (the remote does not see keystrokes anymore, only translated characters, thus transforming keycodes into characters is the responsibility of your client).

Comment: I surely understand that the end machine sees only translated characters. And my question is exactly about how to transform them.